# Hibernate adds unnecessary row in role table after user registration

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a functionality to my webapp with user registration. Webapp is based on spring boot, hibernate and mysql database, frontend is in angular. Generally, the user creation procedure is working correctly, user data is correctly send from frontend to backend via json and saved to the database in shop_user table (with all the user data, such as name, surname, address etc.), but it DOESN'T have role column.

I also have table 'role', which should be:

```
id     name
1      USER
2      ADMIN
```

and joined table user_role, which consists of user_id from table shop_user and role id from table role, so it should look like this:

```
id_user    id_role
1          2
2          1
3          1
```

When user is being created on the website, it is hard-coded to set the role by default to USER. This seems to work quite well as it adds a new row in shop_user, and it adds a row to user_role, but... it also creates a new row in 'role' table.

so in the end 'role' table looks like this:

```
id     name
1      ADMIN
2      USER
3      USER
4      USER
5      USER
99     USER
```

`

while this is not a blocking bug that stops application from working, it is not 'as it should work' unfortunately... as the table should only consist of two role rows (and possibly additional ones, in the future), but not multiplicated for each user!

here's the flawed code of user:

## User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_user")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

@Column
private String firstName;

@Column
private String lastName;

@Column
private String addressLine;

@Column
private String city;

@Column
private String country;

@Column
private String zipCode;

@Column
private String phoneNumber;

@Column
private String email;

@Column
private String password;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_role", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id_user", "id_role"})})
private List<Role> roles;

public User() {
}

public User(User user) {
    setId(user.getId());
    this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
    this.lastName = user.getLastName();
    this.addressLine = user.getAddressLine();
    this.city = user.getCity();
    this.country = user.getCountry();
    this.zipCode = user.getZipCode();
    this.phoneNumber = user.getPhoneNumber();
    this.email = user.getEmail();
    this.password = user.getPassword();
    this.roles= user.getRoles();
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getAddressLine() {
    return addressLine;
}

public void setAddressLine(String addressLine) {
    this.addressLine = addressLine;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Role implementation:

## Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<User> users;

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Abstract entity:

## AbstractEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Persistable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id == null;
    }
}
```

User service:

## UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl extends AbstractServiceImpl<User, UserDTO> implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserConverter userConverter;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, UserConverter 
userConverter) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userConverter = userConverter;
    }

    @Override
    protected JpaRepository<User, Long> getRepository() {
        return userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected Converter<User, UserDTO> getConverter() {
        return userConverter;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User registerUser(User user) {
        List<Role> roles = new LinkedList<>();
        roles.add(new Role("USER"));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }}
```

I am nearly sure that this comes to the relations mapping in Hibernate and object creation, but can't quite figure it out...

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User registerUser(User user) {
    List<Role> roles = new LinkedList<>();
    roles.add(new Role("USER"));
    user.setRoles(roles);
    return userRepository.save(user);
}}
```

Since the relationship User -> Role is cascade persist, the (new) role `new Role("USER")` is also persisted and you ended up with a new Role for each user instead of reusing the existing one.

The solution is to check the existence of a Role with name = USER. If doesn't exist, insert it. Otherwise add the existent one to the `roles` collection.

Comment: so to "add the existent one", I should actually get them from the database from role table, right?

Comment: @Doomsay Right.